# Showing a second TextView layout  in Android 

Tags: android, layout

I am trying create a layout. There are several inner layouts that should like like this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/835/69560035.png/

So there is a main LinearLayout and several layouts inside like the one below.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="30px"
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/gy1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
        </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#222222"
            android:paddingLeft="3px">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#222222"
            android:paddingBottom="5px"
            android:paddingLeft="3px"
            android:background="#D8D8D8"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The second TextView is not shown, and I cannot find out what is wrong with the code. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I've just tested your layout xml and the second TextView does show - if you set the text in the view. Do you set the text programmatically?

Comment: Yes, i set it prgrammatically.

Comment: I deleted every unnecessary code from the xml and was trying for two hours than gave up. RelativeLayout working. I have no idea why linearlayout was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30px"
    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/gy1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:width="30px"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RelativeLayout01">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15px"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#222222"
            android:paddingLeft="3px">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#222222"
            android:paddingBottom="5px"
            android:paddingLeft="3px"
            android:background="#D8D8D8" >
        </TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I didn't want to use relativelayout, but could not do it with linearlayout. thanks

Comment: I was in your same boat.  Apparently RelativeLayouts are more lightweight than LinearLayouts.  Check this out: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="30px" android:layout_height="30px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@drawable/gy1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="15px" android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#222222"
                android:paddingLeft="3px" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="Hello" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textColor="#222222" android:paddingBottom="5px"
                android:paddingLeft="3px" android:background="#D8D8D8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01" android:text="Hello 2222"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"

        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This technique in *[Android Layout Tricks #1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)* may solve your problem.